# Issue with select query in sqlite ios phone gap?

Tags: javascript, ios, sqlite, cordova

can any one help me how can i retrieve value from db? my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  
       // Wait for Cordova to load  
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);  
       // Cordova is ready  
       function onDeviceReady() {  
         console.log("Run1");  
         var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});  
         db.transaction(function (tx) {  
                 tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log)');  
         });  
         db.transaction(function (tx){  
                 for (var index = 1; index < 10; index++){  
                   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id,log) VALUES ('+index+', '+index+')');  
                 }  
         });  
       }  
     </script>
```

here table is created and 10 rows are inserted. But I am not able to retrieve and display the values.

```
    <input id="DBlist" type="submit" onClick='showList()' data-theme="b" value="Saved values"  data-mini="false">

 function showList()
    {
 var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB2"});
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql("select * from LOGS;", [], function(tx, res) {
  // how can I display all the rows in console.log()
   });
   });
  }
```

Any suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at documentation

```
https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin
```

Short rewrite from it:

```
function(tx, res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
        console.log("Row = " + i + ", id = " + res.rows.item(i).id + ", log =  " +
                res.rows.item(i).log);
    }
});
```

Comment: Will try but I am using sqlite plugin not phonegap storage

Comment: @user3300593 I misread your question, yes, but syntax for SQLite plugin remains the same. I changed link to correct documentation